# Does not have matching return type error when using interfaces and generics

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Why am I getting this error and how can I work around it when I CAN'T change the interfaces... (You can copy/paste the code into an empty CS file)

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public interface IEntity
    {
    }

    public interface IEntitySet<T>
    {
    }

    public class Entity : IEntity
    {
    }

    public class EntitySet<T> : IEntitySet<T>
    {
    }

    public interface IImplementer
    {
        IEntitySet<IEntity> Set { get; set; }
    }

    public class Implementer : IImplementer
    {
        // Error 'ClassLibrary1.Implementer' does not implement interface member 'ClassLibrary1.IImplementer.Set'. 
        // 'ClassLibrary1.Implementer.Set' cannot implement 'ClassLibrary1.IImplementer.Set' 
        // because it does not have the matching return type of 'ClassLibrary1.IEntitySet<ClassLibrary1.IEntity>'.
        public EntitySet<Entity> Set { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should be `public IEntitySet<IEntity> Set { get; set; }` because `IEntitySet<IEntity>` is not `EntitySet<Entity>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, your `Set` method is meant to have a return type of `IEntitySet<IEntity>`, but you've tried to declare the implementation using `EntitySet<Entity>`. Two problems there:

- `IEntitySet` isn't `EntitySet`
- `IEntity` isn't `Entity`

The implementation signature has to match the interface exactly.

You should probably make `IImplementer` generic, like this:

```
public interface IImplementer<T> where T : IEntity
{
    IEntitySet<T> Set { get; set; }
}
```

At that point, you can have:

```
public class Implementer : IImplementer<Entity>
{
    public IEntitySet<Entity> Set { get; set; }
}
```

You can then write:

```
var implementer = new Implementer();
implementer.Set = new EntitySet<Entity>();
```

Is that what you want? If you *really* need to force `Implementer` to use `EntitySet` rather than just any `IEntitySet`, then you're probably coupling the two ideas too tightly.

Comment: My question was coming from an EntityFramework context, regarding this feature that EF apperently is not having yet: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1272291-support-interfaces-as-entity-and-complex-types

Comment: I don't think that uservoice post is asking for the same thing. They *want* to be using interfaces at both ends of the chain. But in your example you are trying to force your `Implementer` to use the concrete class `EntitySet`, whereas the interface definition says it only needs to implement the interface `IEntitySet`. Is there a reason you want the concrete class and can't just use the interface?

Comment: Yes, because the class in the real world is "DbSet" and i need to provide it in a from-"DbContext"-inherited class in order to use the EF feature related to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this exception because `IImplementer` requires an `IEntitySet<IEntity> Set` property, but your `Implementer` class is returning an `EntitySet<Entity>`. `EntitySet` can be cast to `IEntitySet`, but `IEntitySet` *cannot* be cast to `EntitySet`, and so the interface implementation fails because you do not satisfy the interface.

Just change `public EntitySet<Entity> Set {get; set;}` to `public IEntitySet<IEntity> Set {get; set;}` on your `Implementer` class.